# Seagate Expansion Portable drive 2 TB Can I run Ubuntu on it like NextCloud Box

Tags: server, nextcloud

is there a small server or Expansion Portable drive with at least 2 TB that will plug into router's ethernet connection to run Ubuntu on and apache, PHP, MySQL and nextcloud

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly than you would like to run Ubuntu with apache, PHP, MySQL and nextcloud in your network.

Such a system is already a full blown server and not a simple extension drive. I would get a small size PC or laptop and install Ubuntu with the requested services. Alternatively you can try the same with a Rasberry Pie or Banana Pie server.